# reboot via dbus-send without interaction?

Tags: systemd, d-bus

trying to investigate why handbrake and kodi cannot shutdown or reboot my system, I narrowed the problem down to these "Interactive authentication required" messages:

```
% dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot boolean:false
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InteractiveAuthorizationRequired: Interactive authentication required.
% dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Reboot boolean:true 
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InteractiveAuthorizationRequired: Interactive authentication required.
```

According to https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1110714-start-0.html and the logind documentation https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/ at least the line with "false" should be able to reboot the system **without** user interaction. How comes?

I tried to get some useful information using dbus-monitor running in parallel on another xterm, but theses commands don't trigger any logging, as it seems. I have also verified package dependencies, went back to old dbus-daemon, tried several ways to run the dbus-launcher, all in vain :-(

System is Debian Sid on amd64, dbus-broker 35-2, systemd 255.4-1+b1, libpam-systemd 255.4-1+b1, upstream kernel 6.8.1. systemctl status can be found below.

Every insightful comment is highly appreciated

Regards

Harri

```
{harri@cecil:~ (master) 1002} zcat systemctl_status.txt.gz 
● cecil.afaics.de
    State: running
    Units: 513 loaded (incl. loaded aliases)
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Sun 2024-03-24 10:53:36 CET; 33min ago
  systemd: 255.4-1+b1
   CGroup: /
           ├─init.scope
           │ └─1 /sbin/init
           ├─system.slice
           │ ├─acpid.service
           │ │ └─839 /usr/sbin/acpid
           │ ├─atd.service
           │ │ └─1211 /usr/sbin/atd -f
           │ ├─autofs.service
           │ │ └─1192 /usr/sbin/automount --pid-file /var/run/autofs.pid
           │ ├─avahi-daemon.service
           │ │ ├─841 "avahi-daemon: running [cecil.local]"
           │ │ └─873 "avahi-daemon: chroot helper"
           │ ├─bluetooth.service
           │ │ └─842 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
           │ ├─clamav-freshclam.service
           │ │ └─1147 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true
           │ ├─cron.service
           │ │ └─1175 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           │ ├─dbus-broker.service
           │ │ ├─878 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope system --audit
           │ │ └─895 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id 4d4981ed2a8267030aa4ffd948e6259c --max-bytes 536870912 --max-fds 4096 --max-matches 16384 --audit
           │ ├─dnsmasq.service
           │ │ └─1210 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service
           │ ├─fsidd.service
           │ │ └─845 /usr/sbin/fsidd
           │ ├─irqbalance.service
           │ │ └─847 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
           │ ├─lighttpd.service
           │ │ └─1314 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
           │ ├─mdmonitor.service
           │ │ └─588 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan
           │ ├─minidlna.service
           │ │ └─1252 /usr/sbin/minidlnad -f /etc/minidlna.conf -P /run/minidlna/minidlna.pid -S -r
           │ ├─networking.service
           │ │ └─1057 dhclient -4 -v -i -pf /run/dhclient.br0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.br0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.br0.leases br0
           │ ├─nfs-blkmap.service
           │ │ └─784 /usr/sbin/blkmapd
           │ ├─nfs-idmapd.service
           │ │ └─1157 /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
           │ ├─nfs-mountd.service
           │ │ └─1172 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd
           │ ├─nfsdcld.service
           │ │ └─791 /usr/sbin/nfsdcld
           │ ├─nvidia-persistenced.service
           │ │ └─857 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvpd
           │ ├─opensmtpd.service
           │ │ ├─1182 /usr/sbin/smtpd
           │ │ ├─1183 "smtpd: crypto"
           │ │ ├─1184 "smtpd: control"
           │ │ ├─1185 "smtpd: lookup"
           │ │ ├─1187 "smtpd: dispatcher"
           │ │ ├─1188 "smtpd: queue"
           │ │ └─1190 "smtpd: scheduler"
           │ ├─polkit.service
           │ │ └─1996 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
           │ ├─rpc-statd.service
           │ │ └─1993 /usr/sbin/rpc.statd
           │ ├─rpcbind.service
           │ │ └─759 /sbin/rpcbind -f -w
           │ ├─rsyslog.service
           │ │ └─855 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
           │ ├─rtkit-daemon.service
           │ │ └─2175 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
           │ ├─smartmontools.service
           │ │ └─858 /usr/sbin/smartd -n
           │ ├─ssh.service
           │ │ └─1392 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"
           │ ├─system-getty.slice
           │ │ ├─getty@tty2.service
           │ │ │ └─5318 /sbin/agetty -o "-p -- \\u" --noclear - linux
           │ │ ├─getty@tty3.service
           │ │ │ └─5326 ssh-agent
           │ │ ├─getty@tty5.service
           │ │ │ └─6017 /sbin/agetty -o "-p -- \\u" --noclear - linux
           │ │ └─getty@tty6.service
           │ │   └─5200 /sbin/agetty -o "-p -- \\u" --noclear - linux
           │ ├─systemd-journald.service
           │ │ └─442 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
           │ ├─systemd-logind.service
           │ │ └─860 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
           │ ├─systemd-timesyncd.service
           │ │ └─760 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
           │ ├─systemd-udevd.service
           │ │ └─udev
           │ │   └─490 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
           │ └─unattended-upgrades.service
           │   └─1160 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
           └─user.slice
             └─user-1000.slice
               ├─session-5.scope
               │ ├─5319 /bin/login -p --
               │ └─5356 -bash
               ├─session-7.scope
               │ ├─5322 /bin/login -p --
               │ ├─5413 -bash
               │ ├─5444 xinit -- :4 -br -quiet
               │ ├─5445 -bash
               │ ├─5446 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/ts
               │ ├─5447 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :4 -br -quiet
               │ ├─5456 /bin/bash /local/home/harri/.xinitrc
               │ ├─5463 /bin/bash /local/home/harri/.xinitrc
               │ ├─5465 /usr/bin/fvwm2
               │ ├─5481 /usr/libexec/fvwm2/2.7.0/FvwmPager 7 4 none 0 8 "*"
               │ ├─5482 xterm -C -n CONSOLE -fn 6x12 -g 120x9+0+0 -j +ut -T /var/log/messages -e tail -F --max-unchanged-stats=5 /var/log/kern.log
               │ ├─5483 xterm -g 80x40+0+148 -n cecil.afaics.de -j
               │ ├─5484 /usr/libexec/fvwm2/2.7.0/FvwmAuto 9 4 none 0 8 500
               │ ├─5485 xterm -g 120x40+519+148 -n cecil.afaics.de -j
               │ ├─5486 xterm -C -n CONSOLE -fn 6x12 -g 80x9+759+0 -j +ut -T /var/log/messages -e watch /sbin/route -n
               │ ├─5487 xpenguin
               │ ├─5488 /usr/libexec/fvwm2/2.7.0/FvwmEvent 11 4 none 0 8
               │ ├─5489 dclock
               │ ├─5491 /bin/bash /local/home/harri/.xinitrc
               │ ├─5494 xscreensaver -no-splash
               │ ├─5496 watch /sbin/route -n
               │ ├─5498 xscreensaver-systemd
               │ ├─5499 bash
               │ ├─5504 bash
               │ ├─5509 tail -F --max-unchanged-stats=5 /var/log/kern.log
               │ ├─5627 emacs
               │ └─6608 systemctl status
               └─user@1000.service
                 ├─app.slice
                 │ ├─emacs.service
                 │ │ └─5352 /usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
                 │ └─gpg-agent.service
                 │   └─5376 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
                 ├─init.scope
                 │ ├─5329 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
                 │ └─5330 "(sd-pam)"
                 └─session.slice
                   ├─dbus-broker.service
                   │ ├─5370 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope user
                   │ └─5377 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id 4d4981ed2a8267030aa4ffd948e6259c --max-bytes 100000000000000 --max-fds 25000000000000 --max-matches 5000000000
                   ├─filter-chain.service
                   │ └─5354 /usr/bin/pipewire -c filter-chain.conf
                   ├─pipewire.service
                   │ └─5353 /usr/bin/pipewire
                   └─pulseaudio.service
                     └─5355 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: Apparently I have to start xinit on the current tty using something like "vt${ttynum} -keeptty" on the Xorg command line.

Using the startx wrapper around xinit the problem went away.